# c++ adding subclass to array of base class?

Tags: c++, arrays, subclass, base-class

i have a class book
and 2 subclass
lerningbook,readingbook
and i am trying to create a list of books 
book* listofbooks
and add to it the subclass

```
Book* listOfBooks;

void Mang::addBookToList(Book b3)
{
    Book* temp;
    temp=listOfBooks;
    lobsize++;
    listOfBooks=new Book[lobsize];
    int i;
    for(;i<lobsize;i++)
    {
        listOfBooks[i]=temp[i];
    }
    listOfBooks[i]=b3;
}
```

problem is when i am trying to send it the subclass this not accpecting it
i tryed to use template so the function will be able to take any class but it didnt help

the error am geting is:
**no suitable user defined conversion from lerningbook to book exsists**
guessing i need to implement same type of function that will allow me to do this but i dont know wich one
hope one of you can help me out thx in adv :)

 (i know i am missing the delete[] on the temp array sort of got stuck on this problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b3` is a `Book`, but `listoOfBooks` is an array of `Book*`. You need to pass a `Book*` to `addBookToList`, not just for the assigment but to avoid [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

If this is not a learning exercise, use a `std::vector<Book*>` instead or a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Book>>`. The `std::vector` will dynamically grow as required and the use of a smart pointer will automatically `delete` the elements when the `vector` is destroyed.

If you choose use of the `Book*` ensure you obey the [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). This could just be making `Mang` non-copyable by declaring the copy constructor and assignment operator `private`.

Note that `i` is uninitialised in `for` loop and the following assignment is out of bounds access on the array as `i == lobsize` after the `for`:

```
listOfBooks[i]=b3;
```

array indexes run from 0, so `lobsize - 1` is the index of the last element.